# Sum of single column across rows based on a condition in Spark Dataframe

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

Consider the following dataframe:

```
+-------+-----------+-------+
|    rid|  createdon|  count|
+-------+-----------+-------+
|    124| 2017-06-15|     1 |
|    123| 2017-06-14|     2 |
|    123| 2017-06-14|     1 |
+-------+-----------+-------+
```

I need to add the `count` column among rows which has `createdon` and `rid` of are same.

Therefore the resultant dataframe should be follows:

```
+-------+-----------+-------+
|    rid|  createdon|  count|
+-------+-----------+-------+
|    124| 2017-06-15|     1 |
|    123| 2017-06-14|     3 |
+-------+-----------+-------+
```

I am using Spark 2.0.2.

I have tried agg, conditions inside select etc, but couldn't find the solution. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.{functions => func}
df.groupBy($"rid", $"createdon").agg(func.sum($"count").alias("count"))
```

Answer (score 0):

this should do what you want:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.sum

df
.groupBy($"rid",$"createdon")
.agg(sum($"count").as("count"))
.show
```